# Calculate middle point of an arc from 2 points and radius

Tags: javascript, math

I draw on a canvas, and when I draw 2 lines like in the photo, I draw an arc. Next, I have to write the angle in the midpoint of the arc, but I don't know how to do it. Do you have any suggestions of how can I get the midpoint (X) of the arc ?

I have :

1. A point
2. B point
3. C point
4. Radius

[image]

Comment: There's a wee ambiguity here. If the angle acb is more than 180 degrees, where should x go? Is it the midpoint of the smaller arc, or the larger one? What if x is exactly 180 degrees?

Comment: Exactly, currently, the angle X is smaller than 180 so it is interior, but I have to do exactly the same thing for the exterior angle, that is also to find the midpoint of the exterior arc and write the angle there. @dmuir

Answer (score 1):

you can calculate the angle `acb`, divide it by 2,
multiply the `sine` of it by the `radius` (which is the distance between `X` and `C`) and its equal to (X<sub>y</sub>) - (C<sub>y</sub>).  add C<sub>y</sub> back and you got X<sub>y</sub>.
you can do the same for X<sub>x</sub> with cosine of the angle divided by 2, and C<sub>x</sub> instead of C<sub>y</sub>.
**used theorems:**
`sin(a)=opposite/hypotenuse.`
`cos(a)=adjacent/hypotenuse.`
`two angles with equal arcs in a circle are equal.` (the point x divide the arc into 2 identical sub arcs and that mean it divides the angle by 2)

Comment: I followed your instructions, but its not working perfectly. My formula for the Xx is: ```Cx + (radius * Math.cos(ABC° / 2))``` and for the Xy: ```Cy + (radius * Math.sin(ABC° / 2))```

Comment: the angle is acb not abc. and is your radius for the big circle or the small one? (should be the small one if you don't have it just calculate the distance between C and B)